# form submit going to new page instead of loading in view of django ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a simple form that I am testing an ajax call from.  The ajax.html file looks like this:

```
<form id="ajaxform" method="get" action="/polls/ajax/submit/">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="input" id="input" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ajaxform').ajaxForm({
            success: ajaxformSubmit,
            dataType: 'json',
            clearForm: true,
            resetForm: true
        });
    });

    function ajaxformSubmit(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        if (responseText['success'] == true) {
            alert("Added item: " + responseText['pk']);
        }

        // returning false inhibits the browser from opening a "Save As" dialog.
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

It's views.py looks like this:

```
def ajax_test(request):
    form = AjaxForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/ajax.html', context)
```

This form submits to this ajax function:

```
def AjaxSubmit( request ):
    GET = request.GET
    results = { 'success' : False }
    form = AjaxForm( request.GET )

    if form.is_valid():
        print form.cleaned_data['input']
        results['success'] = True

    return HttpResponse( simplejson.dumps( results ), mimetype='application/json' )
```

The urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^ajaxform/$', views.ajax_test, name='ajax-test'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns( 'polls.ajax',
    (r'^ajax/submit/$', 'AjaxSubmit' ),

)
```

The problem is that when i go to the page at `http://localhost:8000/polls/ajaxform/` and I submit, the page goes to the json that is returned to url: `http://localhost:8000/polls/ajax/submit/?input=test`  It should stay on the same form page and invoke the json response with the javascript.

I did [this tutorial](http://www.jonhill.ca/programming/ajax-forms-in-django) .

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should `.preventDefault()` or `return false` in the submit callback function to stay on the same page.

Comment: @JonnySooter There is `return false;` in the success callback already. The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the javascript libary:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

After that, it works like a charm.